# The 12.2w dimmable LED bulbs in living room trio wont work after they first turn on, what changes during that first flick?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, dimmer-switch

Installed a set of 75w equivalent (12.2w) dimmable LED bulbs in my living room to replace a trio of 60w equivalent (8.8w) LEDs that were flickering when i dimmed them. The new bulbs seemed to work fine so I put the cover back on and now I can only get them to turn on occasionally. It seems like the first turn after a 'cool-off' period they work and then wont work again.

- I have two switches for the socket set, one with dimmers and one without, seems to work with only the dimmable one but even that I haven't been able to find a pattern of when it works and doesnt.
- The breaker is unaffected, I tried resetting the breaker to make sure but the internet is on the same circuit and thats working fine.
- I tried taking one of the bulbs out the reduce the load to see if that made any difference, still didnt work.
- I read about a 'warm-up' period that may lead to some people thinking the lights aren't working due to impatience, was patient, still didnt work.

Going to switch back to the 60w= and update from there but kinda stumped as to what to do since everything I can think of says there shouldn't be a problem.

Edit: as far as I can tell stackexchange doesnt support threading? so I've answered all the comments below.

! Both switched do work (the dimmable and the on/off, both very intermittently).

- I miss-phrased this, the cover is the glass bowl that is suspended around/below the lights.  the top is very much open.
- Very useful to know about the methods of how LEDs / Dimming interact and dimming 'tech' in general, thank you.
- I think everything in the house is LED but I'll track down some incandescent and see what happens. The strange bit is the bulbs that were being replaced are also LEDs so it really seems like the only difference is the wattage. Idk if the old LEDs were 'dimmable' but they appear to be the same brand as the new ones.
- The dimmer itself, wall outlet. idk its claims, came with the house.

-The bulbs, Make: Feit Electric Model: enhance a19 12.2w LED bulbs.
** I got them from Home Depot. They specifically note that they can be used in enclosed fixtures (which they are not but there was a comment about that).

Comment: Does "I put the cover back on" impliy that these are in a fully enclosed fixture? And they worked without the cover on, and they work after they cool off for a while?

Comment: Dimming LEDs is a black art.  Traditional home dimming is "Triac Dimming", which uses lots of tricks to allow dimmers on incandescent lights without having to add wires to *switch loops*.  It distorts the AC power sine wave very badly, and is not really compatible with how DC drivers on LED lighting work.  "Dimmable" LEDs really struggle to power themselves while trying to infer what the triac dimmer intends.  It's a surprise it works *at all*.  The "watt equivalent" is purely a marketing message, and has no electrical effect of any kind.

Comment: Since the fixture has multiple bulbs, try a test: replace ONE OF THE BULBS  with real incandescent. If that instantly fixes everything, that is very useful data.  (sorry for the all-caps but many people mis-read this advice as "change ALL the bulbs to incandescent and give up on LED forever" which is not what I am saying at all.)

Comment: The dimmer is, or purports to be, LED compatible, or it's "from the before times" and is only designed to work with Incandescents?

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer in question?